# How to write a Kernel module using SPI properly?

Tags: kernel, spi, driver

I have no experience writing kernel modules. I build some examples with gpio interrupts and they worked prety well. Now I want to use SPI from my kernel module and I will explain why I need it.

I am working with a ADC which has a continuous mode, so this device generates a falling edge in a pin warning that there is a new sample available. When this edge is detected, it's necessary to read that sample via SPI. I was trying to do this operation from user space, but I realized that I had not time guarantee.

I wrote a kernel module that when detectes the rising edge, it generates a pulse with the same width that my reading will take. In the interrupt pin I applied a square wave with the same period that my ADC's sample rate. With an oscilloscope I monitored the signals. And the time accuracy results where very good, they fit my application very well.

I follow the same method with a code in user space and the results in oscilloscope where a total disaster. That's why I believe I have to read my SPI bus from kernel space.

I was taking a look at spidev source code, but I am not sure about all the things I have to implement. Does anybody have some example reading and writing to SPI from kernel space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At a glance the protocol looks pretty simple, simpler than even UART (although all I did was glance and there may be more to it): https://www.circuitbasics.com/basics-of-the-spi-communication-protocol/

Comment: @goldilocks, thanks for your answer. I know the protocol is simple, but the BCM2835 has integrated SPI, so I would like to use the hardware solution, without having to manage gpio pins on my own. The same way we have linux/gpio.h api, we have linux/spi.h. But I have no experience using this API. I would appreciate if anybody could help me sending some example.

Comment: Ah right, silly me.  The hardware does the protocol (flex: I've implemented UART using an FPGA before and was thinking like that about it).  Have you looked at the kernel docs?  Dunno if they have any relevance: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/spi/index.html

Comment: @goldilocks, I am following this documentantion, but it's a kind of hard for me. Because as I said,  I have no experience writing kernel modules. I will try more and I let you know if I have new progress. Right now I am reading SPI kernel docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/spi.html

Comment: I've only fooled around a bit with writing kernel modules, and it has been a long time; I'm no expert.  The best place for general questions about that will be Stack Overflow; there is also a quite busy mail list, the LKML. I am not sure what the possibilities are there re seeking advice like this.  Also, although it is getting on in years, if you have not yet you should have a look at the the LDD3: https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ (there never was an LDD4, btw). It should be helpful with general stuff; various people maintain updated versions of the code examples: https://github.com/search?q=ldd3